# Overlapping of highchart with it's series text

Tags: highcharts

I'm getting some overlap with Highcharts and it's series text (when categories are more than 10)

I'm not able to get any CSS control of Highchart as well.

Please suggest better way to fix this overlap issue.

[image]

Comment: This is working correct outside my application - See this fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/1pe9ow94/). but Not sure what is going wrong with my application highcharts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `margin top` and `margin bottom` for legend items. Also you can change their `padding`.

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.itemMarginBottom
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.itemMarginTop
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.padding

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/273cm0s6/